# How can I make my MySQL queries more efficient in Go?

Tags: mysql, database, go

I am writing an API in Go (my first hands on with the language) and I have some MySQL queries in loops. When it runs on a larger query it can take more than 7-10 seconds to reply and often times out. Is there a way to make these queries a little more efficient? Is it simply a matter of DB structure, or even more simply server spec?

Server spec is a cheap single core VPS with 512mb RAM.

Go Code for query:

```
//Vendor search
reply, err: = db.Query("SELECT * FROM manuf_ids WHERE id='" + manuf + "';")
if err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}

for reply.Next() {
    var manufacturer Manufacturer
    err = reply.Scan( & manufacturer.ID, & manufacturer.Desc)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    replytwo, err: = db.Query("SELECT id,descrip FROM dev_ids WHERE manuf='" + manuf + "';")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    for replytwo.Next() {
        var devices Device
        err = replytwo.Scan( & devices.ID, & devices.Desc)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        //Get sub-devices
        replythree, err: = db.Query("SELECT id,descrip FROM sub_dev_ids WHERE parent='" + devices.ID + "';")
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }

        for replythree.Next() {
            var sub_devices Sub
            err = replythree.Scan( & sub_devices.ID, & sub_devices.Desc)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err.Error())
            }
            devices.Subs = append(devices.Subs, sub_devices)
        }
        replythree.Close()
        manufacturer.Devs = append(manufacturer.Devs, devices)
    }
    replytwo.Close()
    results = append(results, manufacturer)
}
reply.Close()
```

I have read a little about preparing queries, and I use that in another function for writing to the DB, but I am not sure if that will help here. I did remove my defers from the loops and that helped, but marginally.

Comment: There's a ton of different things you can do, from DB optimization, to code optimization, to increased hardware... this is impossibly broad. You should absolutely being using prepared queries (really never build queries with strings as you have in the code quoted), but that probably won't make a big performance difference. How big are the data sets? What's CPU/RAM usage look like? Do you have indexes on these tables? How long do the queries take individually? How many are you running? Have you tried it with joins and compared performance?

Comment: One thing off the bat, _never ever_ concatenate strings into your query.  That's how you get SQL injection.  For example, what if your `manuf` variable ended up having the value `''; DROP TABLE manuf_ids CASCADE; --`  Running your query now drops your entire table, and anything else that references it.  Always use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: Also, do you have those tables indexed on the columns you're filtering on?  Indexing makes a _huge_ different in query time.

Comment: I indexed the columns as recommended, and it helped marginally. I moved the program and database to my more powerful VPS and it seems to have solved the issue of speed. I also have those strings going through a test to only allow 4 hex characters and nothing else. That should prevent injections?